# (Psutil) speed net, mtu and isup don't change automatically

Tags: python, performance, psutil

When I run the script, speed, mtu and isup doesn't change automatically. Only if I finish the process and start another time.

```
import psutil
import time
import os

stats = psutil.net_if_stats()

while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    os.system("clear")
  for nic, addrs in psutil.net_if_addrs().items():
            print("%s:" % (nic))
            if nic in stats:
                st = stats[nic]
                print("    stats          : ", end='')
                print("speed=%sMB, mtu=%s, up=%s" % (
                    st.speed, st.mtu,
                    "yes" if st.isup else "no"))
```

I tried to get speed, mtu and isup of each addresses associated to each NIC (network interface card) and changing in this repeat loop, but it doesn't works like this.

Comment: Have you looked in the psutil library for caching?

Comment: BTW, `os.system("clear")` is a crazy amount of inefficiency -- all the `clear` executable does is write a single character to the terminal. You can just write that character yourself and avoid having to start a whole new process.

Comment: what is `stats`? How do you get it? Maybe you should get it inside loop to get fresh data.

Comment: Heh, good point -- `stats` is undefined in this code, and consequently the purported [mre] isn't.

Comment: Thanks guys, I just updated the code putting stats. @CharlesDuffy, I thought was good to put clear, to clear automatically, not manually.

Comment: I just tried to Start and Stop the script and no matter what I do, speed at least, doesn't change. In psutil documentation is not shown loops with net_if_stats()

Comment: @GabrielBifon, if you want to clear the screen from Python, `sys.stderr.write("\033c")` is upwards of a thousand times faster than running `clear` and does the _exact same thing_ (but without starting a copy of `sh` and telling that copy of `sh` to start a copy of `clear` and then waiting for both `clear` and `sh` to exit).

Comment: @GabrielBifon, you should run `stats = psutil.net_if_stats()` again in your loop if you want it to be updated more than once. Right now you only create `stats` once on startup, so _of course_ its content doesn't change since startup.

Comment: Thanks for advices!! Yeah, I tried inside the loop, but nothing happens.